# Why is React Native app not installing after successful build with expo?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

**After successful building expo app, it wont install in any phone.**
This may be very easy but have tried all i know to fix this but didn't work.
This is my craziest experience since i have been working on react...
***Below are the steps i take from installing the app to building it***

1. npm install expo-cli --global
2. expo init my-new-project
3. cd my-new-project => expo start
4. npm install -g exp
5. expo build:android //i choose "Let Expo handle the process!"

**Here's my app.json**

```
{
"expo": {
    "name": "project",
    "slug": "my-new-project",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "35.0.0",
    "platforms": [
        "ios",
        "android",
        "web"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
    "splash": {
        "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
        "resizeMode": "contain",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
        "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
        "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
        "supportsTablet": true,
        "bundleIdentifier": "com.project.test"
    },
    "android": {
        "package": "com.project.test"
    }
}
}
```

**Here's my package.json**

```
{
"name": "project",
"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
"scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest --watchAll"
},
"jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/samples": "~3.0.3",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
    "@react-navigation/web": "^1.0.0-alpha.9",
    "expo": "^35.0.0",
    "expo-asset": "^7.0.0",
    "expo-constants": "^7.0.0",
    "expo-font": "^7.0.0",
    "expo-web-browser": "^7.0.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.3.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^3.12.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^7.0.0",
    "jest-expo": "^35.0.0"
},
"private": true
}
```

**Please any help?**

Comment: try react-native run-android !

Comment: @TusharPandey that command is for pure react native app, in expo you can start via expo start

Comment: yeah but internally if use react-native run-android.

Comment: @TusharPandey can't i run expo build:android and it will generate installable apk?..
I'm good at reactJs. That's why i choosed expo since i don't need much native codes

Comment: Does it mean this is a general issue with Expo?

Comment: How are you trying to install the app on your phone? What is the error message? Are the phones you’re trying to install the app on running Android 5 or newer? (Expo doesn’t support Android versions below 5.)

Comment: are you in same network ? because in left in expo-blunder ... there are options to use , try them ?

Comment: @StanisławChmiela Thanks for your response..
The error is "App not installed".
I'm trying to installing the apk generated by expo.
My phone is android 8 . I dont think if it's installing in any android version

Comment: hmmm , just go to setting -> application and remove your app from there if it is present !

Comment: @TusharPandey Thanks for your response..
I dont know any other option...
All i wanted is to build a react native app written as reactjs. (since expo support JavaScript, i when for it)

Comment: developer option enabled in your device ?

Comment: @TusharPandey the apk is not installing. So there no way it will be in my phone applications. Or do you mean Expo account settings?

Comment: @TusharPandey  YES developer option is enabled on my phone

Comment: What are you getting while installing the apk ? I mean are you getting some error screen or etc

Comment: @ZeeshanAnsari Thanks for your response.
The error message ss "App not installed"

Comment: Okay, uninstall the previous application form application settings if there is. Then switch off the mobile and then install try to install there is a problem with application settings

Comment: @ZeeshanAnsari ok have restarted my phone now and it still saying the same thing..
What exactly should i do in application settings?

Comment: let me know publish app on expo is working or not ?

Comment: @ZeeshanAnsari here's the app https://expo.io/@fanstweet/my-new-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
Find your way to developer options in your phone settings and disable it as it shows in the picture above.
That's how I solved mine. 
Hope that will work for you.

Comment: Thanks. i just did it and the apk installed successfully now.